# Alternative to WCF for client-server application in vb.net express?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, client-server, visual-studio-express

I'm working on a multi-user phonebank software. I originally was planning to use Windows Communication Foundation. However, I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express, and while I can create WCF clients, I can't create a WCF server. As a college student, I don't have the money for Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and while it's available through the DreamSpark program, the licensing terms don't allow for commercial use (I'm hoping to develop a low-cost phonebank system [this isn't a homework assignment; I'm actually an accounting student]).

Are there any alternatives to WCF I can use? My proposed application design is as follows:

1. Job created on server which has all the phone numbers to be called from a database (that is, the person creating the job, from a general database, can create a filtered list of phone numbers to be called). These numbers go into a queue.
2. Clients connect to the server, logging in. As each client connects, it's passed a number from the queue.
3. As each caller finishes a call, they push a button indicating the response from that call. The client then sends an update message to the server, and is given the next number in the queue in response.

I'm speculating here, but couldn't I use an SQL database for both the general list and the filtered list? That is, each list is in its own table, and have a variable pointing to the next database record in the filtered list. When a client requested a record, it would send the next record, and when the client updated a record, it could send a SQL statement making the appropriate change.

I've heard of transactions and caching, do I need to use them for an application of this type? If so, how would I?

I would then use System.Net or something like it for the connecting the client to the server, right?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: There should not be any issue creating WCF Service using the express edition. Are you sure, this is documented somewhere?

Comment: In regards to the 2008 Express edition of VB, there's [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531269%28v=VS.90%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531269%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). I can't find anything regarding VB 2010, aside from the lack of a WCF server template.

Comment: It seems, the templates are not installed/packaged with the express edition. You may however copy the templates from any professional edition installation or try looking for it online. This is suggested in this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552362.aspx

Comment: Would the callers be connecting to this service over the internet? Or on a lan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build your server as a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) service. There are numerous frameworks out there for doing this (eg, [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/), [OpenRasta](http://openrasta.org/), [Resources over MVC](http://rom.codeplex.com/)). It's a very popular way to build services these days, as it has many benefits including simplicity, it's easier to scale than many other types of services, and you can build cross-platform clients (including Windows Forms and HTML/Javascript, but literally anything with an HTTP client stack can be a client).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one approach you could use would be to Use a SQL Server database, write SQL stored procedures to access your data in SQL tables and implement your Server functionality.  You would use .Net's SqlClient to call these stored procedures (and *not* System.Net).

Alternatively, you could just write a *Windows* Service (instead of a WCF Service) and call that using RPC, or System.NET, or .Net Remoting, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what version of visual studio you are using.

I am not sure why you think you are unable to create a WCF service.

A WCF service can be coded in any version of visual studio.

**UPDATE**

OK so you are asking if VB Express can auto-generate a test client? Well I'm not sure but this functionality is not needed to work with WCF. You can easily code your own test client.

There are about five million examples of this on Google. Here's one of them:
http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: I know the screencast I watched on creating a WCF service showed that regular Visual Studio created a WCF test client for testing your service. Does VB Express have that capability as well?

Comment: The Ralf Westphal site doesn't seem to host his example code any more but is still worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

WCF service is nothing but a class library project. So create a class library project, add reference to system.servicemodel and system.runtime.serialization and off you go. WCF is the best choice for any distributed system development in .Net.